# How to tell which node is executing code as it executes in Slurm?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, hostname, slurm

I am very new to Slurm and distributed/parallel computing so hoping someone could shed some light on my issue but bearing in mind this might be a bonehead simple problem to solve.

I've set up a cluster using 6 slave Pi3s (and 1 master) and installed the Slurm workload manager to help with allocation of resources etc.

Before I get into more complex code, I am trying to test something super simple. I am sending the same command to all my nodes, and printing the hostname of the node.

My current code (that works) is:

```
srun --nodes=6 hostname
```

and returns:

```
node01
node05
node04
node02
node06
node03
```

Now I try to run the same type of command using sbatch with the following script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #SBATCH --nodes=6
 #SBATCH --partition=partition
 #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1

 cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
 srun printf ‘Hello from: %s\n’ $(hostname) >> out.txt
```

expecting a similar result as above, but instead I get:

```
Hello from: node01
Hello from: node01
Hello from: node01
Hello from: node01
Hello from: node01
Hello from: node01
```

I tried playing around with the SLURM_NODEID and SLURMD_NODENAME env variables but still couldn't get it to do what I wanted.

I just want to know which node is running the code. The purpose is so that further down the line I am able to trace which operations are done by which nodes for more complex scripts. Maybe compare the performance between nodes that are expected to be "identical". Perhaps even trace which nodes are performing what portion of a parallelized case?

Many thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `printf ‘Hello from: %s\n’ $(hostname) >> out.txt` is evaluated by Bash before it is offered to `srun`. So basically your script is equivalent to

```
HOST=$(hostname)
srun printf ‘Hello from: %s\n’ $HOST >> out.txt
```

This runs the same `printf` command with the same variable expanded. If you simply run

```
srun hostname
```

in your submission script you will see a result identical to the one you obtain when running `srun` directly (outside of a submission script)

If you want to run `printf` you should do something like this:

```
srun bash -c "printf 'Hello from: %s\n' \$(hostname)" >> out.txt
```

Comment: still getting the same result...I'm not bent on using printf so if you have anything other suggestion please let me know..I just want to perform some kind of task i.e. say hello then follow it with the node that performed it

Comment: this worked for me thanks, could you explain why this worked and your previous post didnt? just so I can understand how to expand upon this

Comment: I am not entirely sure why to be honest. It all has to do with the order of operations and the escaping. `\$(hostname)`  does not seem to work outside of quotes.

Comment: In any case, thank you, I will attempt to build upon this for more complex situations